# How to I add validation for user not present in the database after open AM Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, openam

```
class OpenAMStrategy < Base
        def valid? 
            puts("*************** CHECKING OPEN AM VALID ABXXXAB ********")                
            request.headers['uid'].present?
            return true
        end
```

Here i need to add validation after open AM authentication if user present in database it should login ,otherwise it had to show some error message

```
def authenticate!
            puts("******************** DOING OPEN AM AUTHENTICATE ----")
            userName = uidHeader
            user = User.find_by_email(userName)
            if user
            request.headers.env.select do |k, _| 
                k.downcase.start_with?('http') ||
                k.in?(ActionDispatch::Http::Headers::CGI_VARIABLES)
                headerValue = _ if k.downcase.starts_with?('http')
                puts("************  HEADER >>>> #{k} VALUE --> #{headerValue}")
            end
```

Comment: What is an "AM authentication"?

Comment: Its name used for authentication,can you please tell how to add validation,if user not present in database

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this guide is useful for you:

In creation process, if username has to present you can add this code to your model:

```
validates :username, presence: true
```

if you want to save uniq value you can add something like this:

```
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

uniqueness on a special scope:

```
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :account_id }
```

you can create your own special validation method if you like(for example):

```
validate :check_valid_last_name


def check_valid_last_name
    # your special code 
    #  ...
    #  return something
end
```